# Using Push notifications behind corporate proxy. Is this possible?

Tags: rocket.chat

I am running a Rocket Chat 3.7.1 docker compose instance behind a corporate proxy server and we are having trouble getting push notifications working.

Has anyone been able to get this working before?
If so could you share the details of how you got it working please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up publishing our own custom builds of mobile apps that were signed appropriately for their platform.

Then, our settings disabled debugging, disabled the gateway, set production, and all the certificate/key values were set to what were generated for APN and GCM.